# IBM worklight 6 with Xcode 5

Tags: macos, xcode5, ibm-mobilefirst, osx-mavericks

I updated my Lion to Mavericks recently and I found that I cant run with XCode in Worklight 6 Eclipse

Any idea what's happening ?
or somebody can still deploy apps to xcode?

Comment: You don't deploy apps to XCode. What you do instead is deploy an app to the Application server (which is WebSphere Liberty if you're using Worklight Studio). As Idan mentions, it helps to mention the exact problem you're seeing

Answer (score 0):

This is my system:

- OS X 10.9 "Mavericks"
- Xcode 5.0.1
- Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2)
- Worklight Studio 6.0.0.20130926 (also known as v6.0.0.1 - latest Developer Edition provided via the Eclipse Marketplace)

I can successfully:

1. Create a new Worklight project
2. Add the iPhone environment
3. Right-click on the iphone folder and choose > Run As > Xcode project
4. The app is built and deployed to the Worklight Server, and Xcode 5.0.1 opens up with the generated Xcode project
5. Click Run
6. Have the app run in the iOS 7 Simulator

I can also do the same with the latest v5.0.6.1 release of Worklight, as well as v6.1.0 (to be released in the coming weeks).

You will need to Edit Your Question with more **exact** information on your scenario.